# How to transpose and convert data to table view

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

How can I change this:

```
Color 1     :     Blue
Color 2     :     Black
Color 1     :     Yellow
Color 2     :     Green
Color 3     :     Blue
```

Into this:

```
Color_1 Color_2 Color_3
Blue    Black
Yellow  Green   Blue
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried? The idea is to help you solve a problem you have, not to write your software ...

Comment: Just [google stackexchange transpose awk](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange+transpose+awk) and pick a result that does what you want.

Comment: I was able to remove all spaces with sed using the replace argument and many times as needed with -e. But I still cannot make the columns format, I know it can be done with sed or awk
My current output looks like this:
Color 1 Blue
Color 2 Black
Color 1  Yellow
Color 2 Green
Color 3  Blue

Comment: That would not be a good starting point as it's not necessary and the correct answer will not involve sed. Again, just google it and look at the answers. Also, please show your attempt and anything else relevant in your question, don't add it spread out in comments where it's hard for us to find and easy to miss.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980/1745001 (in particular the script I added in that answer using meaningful variable names might help you understand the approach). Just set `-F '[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*' -v OFS='\t'` for your input/output field separator and pipe the output of the awk command to `column -s$'\t' -t` to get tabular (as opposed to tab-separated) final output.

Comment: awk '{for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) { a[NR, f] = $f } }NF > nf { nf = NF }END {for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) {for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS)}}}' file This is the closest I could use, but this only transpose the data and wont make the desired table format

Comment: I don't see you using the FS and OFS settings I suggested nor do I see you pipe the output to `column` as I suggested. [Again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650502/how-to-transpose-and-convert-data-to-table-view#comment1220630_650502) though - **please show your attempt and anything else relevant in your question, don't add it spread out in comments where it's hard for us to find and easy to miss.**

Comment: Why are the shorter columns bottom-aligned, even though columsn are filled in order from top-down?